# I can't find Flask package clicking on + sign in File-->Settings-->Project:project_name-->Project Interpreter

Tags: python, flask, pycharm

I have been trying to install the flask in pycharm but I don't see any option to implement the following instructions...

In pycharm, Go to: File-->Settings-->Project:project_name-->Project Interpreter.

Click on the + sign search for Flask. Choose it and click on Install package

There is a Default setting button not "Settings", moreover clicking on project interpreter under it show me noting, I have to click on all project interpreter then it shows me the screen like attached.[image]

Also when I click on the "+" button underneath it shows me the screen like this..[image]

Can anyone help me to understand how can I install the flask package in pycharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open settings, press <kbd>⌘ ,</kbd>. Find `Project Interpreter` entry and press `+` at the bottom:

[image]

Then search for flask and install it:

[image]

Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: I do not see any packages like it showed in your screen and the "+" button at bottom is not active.. for settings, I go to file and click on default settings and got the options like you.

Comment: Is there any chance you have opened "Preferences for New Projects"? Have you tried to open settings window using hotkey Command and `,` (comma)?

Comment: yes I did it and it worked this time. Thank you so much. I am new to python and flask and having hard time to understand the small things. I appreciate  your time. :-)